# Posting complex Class using Flurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, flurl

First, I have a class:

```
public class EnrolleeViewModel : EntityBase
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public long TenantID { get; set; }
        public string EnrolleeNo { get; set; }
        public byte[] Passport { get; set; }
        public string EnrolledBy { get; set; }
        public string SystemName { get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
        public string EnrolleeType { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string OtherName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<EnrolleeFingerViewModel> enrolleeFingers { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, I have a Web API 4.0 action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(nameof(PostEnrollmentForStudent))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostEnrollmentForStudent(EnrolleeViewModel model)
{

}
```

**Problem:**
Am trying to post an instance of `EnrolleeViewModel` class to the Web API action, But this only works when `Passport` property of the class has no value.

Am posting using Flurl with the below code:

```
            try
            {
                EnrolleeViewModel model = new EnrolleeViewModel()
                {
                    UserID = GlobalResources.UserViewModel.ID,
                    MacAddress = Utils.GetMacAddress(),
                    SystemName = Environment.MachineName,
                    EnrolleeNo = txtRegistrationNo.Text,
                    EnrolleeType = EnrolleeType.STUDENT.ToString(),
                    Passport = AppConverter.ConvertImageToByte(clagPassportEnrollment1.passportPictureBox.Image),
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    LastName = LastName,
                    FirstName = FirstName,
                    OtherName = MiddleName,
                    Phone = PhoneNo,
                    Email = Email,
                    enrolleeFingers = new List<EnrolleeFingerViewModel>(),
                };

                List<EnrolleeFingerViewModel> fingers = new List<EnrolleeFingerViewModel>();
                foreach (var finger in clagFingerEnrollment1.enrolledFingers)
                {
                    model.enrolleeFingers.Add(new EnrolleeFingerViewModel()
                    {
                        FingerData = finger.FingerData,
                        HandType = finger.HandType,
                        FingerType = finger.FingerType,
                        FingerIndex = finger.FingerIndex,
                        FingerRawImage = finger.FingerRawImage,
                        SDKType = finger.SDKType,
                    });
                }

                var url = Url.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.EndPointBase, Properties.Settings.Default.EndPointCreateEnrollment);

                IFlurlResponse response = url.AllowAnyHttpStatus().PostJsonAsync(model).Result;
                if (response.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, $"{txtRegistrationNo.Text} enrolled successfully", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    ResetData();
                }
                else if(response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    dynamic result = response.GetJsonAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
                    throw new Exception(result.Message ?? "Request not successful");
                }
            }
            catch (FlurlHttpException x)
            {
                HandleFormError(x);
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                HandleFormError(x);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is from ASP Web API configuration limit. I simple added the below setting to web.config

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000"/>
    </system.web>
```

The `maxRequestLength="10000"` solved it for me